# Objective-c multiply equality with or in if statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, switch-statement

I don't really understand what is the difference between the these two:

```
If (self.someEnum == someEnumValue1 || self.someEnum == someEnumValue2)
{
// Do some stuff
}
```

and

```
If (self.someEnum == (someEnumValue1 | someEnumValue2) )
{
// Do some stuff
}
```

The second one is obviously not working, but it not give any warnings or errors, but i have no idea what it is for.

I thought it work like this switch:

```
switch (self.someEnum){
    case someEnumValue1:
    case someEnumValue2:
    {
    // Do some stuff
    }
    break;

    default: break;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, you are doing a bitwise `OR` and then comparing the result with `self.someEnum`.
This is usefull when working with bitFlags (i.e) you can store a value with different possibilities of combinations, like above:

```
enumWeekDays = kWeekDaySunday | kWeekDayMonday;

if (enumWeekDays & kWeekDayTursday == kWeekDayTursday ) ... //will not enter here
if (enumWeekDays & kWeekDayMonday == kWeekDayMonday ) ... //will enter here
```

Just to clarify:

```
kWeekDaySunday = 1 ==> 00000001
kWeekDayMonday = 2 ==> 00000010

enumWeekDays = 00000001 OR 00000010 ==> 00000011
```

With the bitwise AND you can compare, like this:

```
if ( 00000011 //enumWeekDays
     00000010 //kWeekDayMonday 
    --------- //and
     00000010 ==> kWeekDayMonday!!
```

Answer (score 1):

`|` is a bitwise `OR` operator, so your line;

```
if (self.someEnum == (someEnumValue1 | someEnumValue2) )
```

where someEnumValue1 = 5 and someEnumValue2 = 2 would end up being;

```
if (self.someEnum == (5 | 2) )
```

which is the same as

```
if (self.someEnum == 7 )
```

...which, if someEnum were one of 5 or 2 would not match either.

There are basically two ways of doing what you want to do, either do the comparison individually as you do, or use a `switch/case`;

```
switch(self.someEnum) {
  case 5:
  case 2:
    ...do your stuff if 5 or 2...
    break;
  default:
    ...and here you do your stuff if they're not...
}
```

The latter can be useful if there are many comparisons, your current version is usually more readable for few cases.

Comment: Ohhh, now i get it, thank you.
So if i want to make something like
`if (self.someEnum == (5 OR 2) )` than the shortest solution is my first example?

Comment: @TussLászló If you want to compare both with someEnum, then yes. Added an alternative though.